# How to change padding using php in options framework

Tags: php, css

In my options framework I have an option to change the padding.  The option creates an ID/variable of "footer_bottom_padding" and then I used this code to change the top and bottom padding. In this example let's say the user selected 50px in the options panel.

NOTE: footer_bottom_padding is the name of the section, not just trying to acheive bottom padding.  Trying to acheive Top/Bottom padding on this section.

```
<?php
if ($smof_data['footer_bottom_padding'] != '') {
echo '.footer-bottom { padding-top: ' . $smof_data['footer_bottom_padding']   . 'px!important; }';
echo '.footer-bottom { padding-bottom: ' . $smof_data['footer_bottom_padding'] . 'px!important; }';
}
?>
```

This outputs it into css to have two different lines of code:

```
padding-bottom:50px !important;
padding-top:50px !important;
```

This works fine but I would like to know how to have one line that would output to css as:

```
padding:50px 0 !important;
```

Comment: You should probably ditch this "options framework" you are using and look into something like SASS or LESS for handling dynamic stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out what you're after, but here is an answer to what I THINK you're after

```
<?php
if ($smof_data['footer_bottom_padding']) {
    echo '.footer_bottom { padding: ', $smof_data['footer_bottom_padding'], 'px 0!important; }';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I was just placing the "0" in the wrong spot, long day.  Thanks.